# Find out solution for an regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex

Here is an search parameter like "ط*س".
And its search result is something like "اسکی حمام اسکی طاس".
We need an regular expression in PHP to find an part of that search result containing "ط*س" . Here * contain only one character.

So, its matching result is "طاس" .

Comment: Try splitting your words on each letter and joining them on `[^\W\d_]*` ensuring the Unicode `u` flag is set.

Comment: Note that you should also `preg_quote` each letter after you split it into an array.